# Library to create trend chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts, angular-nvd3

I am trying to create a trend chart in JavaScript. I went through some of the libraries and noticed that -

1. D3.js - does not have an option to create a trend chart
2. Highcharts.js - cannot create a trend chart in Highcharts.js without the help of plug-ins?

Please suggest a library to create a trend chart.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment, so by doing a simply search, this is what I found: 
Plotting a **trendline** with D3.js http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/33a9e350516da54a5d4f

Maybe submit an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks... :) I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: No problem, I think it was a bit unfair you were down voted without being given a explanation or comment on why you were down voted.

Comment: Exactly... i don't even know why my question is down voted, cause i thought it's very fair question and i have done analysis on it as well, i thought i will get few suggestions on which library to use for trend chart with explanation with advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Pretty straightfroward:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  This isn't the kind of question that SO is here for.  | http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask